# ElasticSearch filter by geo location with value or null value

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation

I'm adding businesses into ElasticSearch. Some are geo located (lon,lat coordinates), some are online businesses only (no coordinates).

What I'm trying to do is to create a query where I filter businesses with a given geo position and a radius. And I would like to include thoses online businesses (without geo coordinates).

Do you have any ideas how to do that?

I've tried this:

```
GET /organizations/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must_not": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "geocoords"
        }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "geo_distance" : {
          "distance" : "200km",
          "geocoords" : {
            "lon": -73.57,
            "lat": 45.45
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I got no result:

```
{
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

This is the data I have:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "organizations",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "is_active" : true,
          "name": "Compagny Inc.",
          "geocoords" : {
            "lon" : -73.5761003,
            "lat" : 45.4560316
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any tips or advices? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current query is mutually exclusive -- you first filter out valid coords and then perform a radial search...

Instead, you may want a logical OR -- either in the radius OR no coords at all:

```json
GET organizations/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": {
              "geo_distance": {
                "distance": "200km",
                "geocoords": {
                  "lon": -73.57,
                  "lat": 45.45
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "geocoords"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```